# How to change the font of Visual Studio Code's UI?

Tags: linux, user-interface, fonts, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out how to change the font used in non-editor tabs in Visual Studio Code; right now this is what I'm getting (zoom the picture to better see what I'm referring to):

[image]

As you can see, a Serif font is used on these non-editor tabs (extension info, Git Graph tab, etc.), making it quite unpleasant and really hard to read.

This happened all of a sudden, I'm quite sure that it is not the default and a nicer and more readable Sans font was used before (like on the left panel), until this problem occurred. I've tried to find if it is possible to change this from inside VSC, but I'm only able to change the fonts used in the editor tabs.

I don't know why and how this behavior has started, and I'm not really sure if this issue is caused  by VSC itself, by an extension, by the OS, or something else.

If it matters, I'm working on Linux, on a fully updated openSUSE Tumbleweed with KDE, and like I said this problem started to manifest itself only recently, it was not how it worked by default.

Any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: [this is an old issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519). try this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does not offer convenient solution out of the box to change the UI font family.

But a developer created the **Customize UI plugin for VS Code.**

#### ⚠️ EDIT 02/01/2023: following the version `1.74`, the Customize UI plugin no longer work, see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519#issuecomment-1344050192). There is currently no ways to change the font in VSCode.

#### Setup

1. Install the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) plugin
2. Restart VS Code
3. Open VS Code Settings
4. Change Customize UI Font:Monospace to `Fira Code`
5. Change Customize UI Font:Regular to `Helvetica Nueve` or `Arial` depending on your OS

Alternativaly, you can edit those settings using the json settings editor as follow:

```
    "customizeUI.font.regular": "Helvetica Nueve",
    "customizeUI.font.monospace": "Fira Code",
```

[GitHub issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Customize UI plugin no longer works. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519#issuecomment-1344050192

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kencocaceo.customvscodeuicss This one worked! Although after applying, vs code throws "Your code installation appears to be corrupt".

Comment: readers might be interested in https://github.com/drcika/apc-extension#fontfamily (I have no affiliation).

Answer (score 3):

vscode is an electron app so you can actually just open up the developer tools in the help menu, look up the location of `workbench.desktop.main.css` under the source tab, make a backup and edit the font-family rule for your OS.
There's a pretty gnarly-phrased notification that pops up  about vscode being corrupted, however the linked-documentation is fairly clear it's just unsupported officially.

Answer (score 1):

The current best solution for changing the UI font is to use the "Fonted" extension in VSCode.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=degreat.fonted

Follow the instructions, and you should be good to go

Comment: I think this corrupted my vscode install

Answer (score 0):

In most of the Linux distributions we get the option to change the fonts systemwide if you are okay with changing the system font.